# syncdb - no such table error

Tags: django, syncdb

When I try syncdb on my project , I've got error:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: main_region
```

forms.py

```
from main.models import Region 
class ChangeState(forms.Form):
     region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Region.objects.all(),required=False) 
     state = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
```

models.py

```
 class Region(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When I was comment line:

```
region = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Region.objects.all(),required=False)
```

syncdb  works OK.

What's going on ?

Thanks in advance for explain.

Answer (score 2):

Did you forget to add 'main' to your apps in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ModelChoiceField for the region in the form.